# How to use Extension in selenium with vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need help Belows code for java. need to convert vba

public void setUp() {

String pathToExtension = “C:\Users\ian\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\bihmplhobchoageeokmgbdihknkjbknd\4.1.0_0”;

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments(“–load-extension=” + pathToExtension);

driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

}

i tried below code in vba .but not working

Dim bot As New WebDriver

StrMainURL="www.google.com"

ExtensionPath = "C:\Users\ian\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\bihmplhobchoageeokmgbdihknkjbknd\4.1.0_0"

bot.AddArgument ("–load-extension=" + ExtensionPath)

bot.start "chrome", StrMainURL

Comment: Try to replace this line `bot.AddArgument ("–load-extension=" + ExtensionPath)` with this `bot.AddArgument("--load-extension=" & ExtensionPath)`